# I can't see the comments in a PDF file that were added in macOS

Tags: mac, windows, pdf

I wrote a proposal and sent it in PDF form to my supervisor. She highlighted the proposal and left comments, but I can't see these comments when the PDF is opened in Windows or Ubuntu. I tried foxit reader and Adobe Reader, but in both, the highlights *are* visible, but comments appear as empty rectangles. Are there any apps or online web sites that I can use to see the comments?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Are you able to add some more details such as what your supervisor used to review the PDF (e.g. Mac v PC, and what software). Also, have you tried opening the file with Preview just to see what happens? Finally, please advise what version of macOS you're running.

Comment: @Monomeeth - I think the OP created and is reading the returned PDF in a non-macOS environment and the supervisor opened and commented on a macOS system. I edited to make this clearer. User137927 - I think the problem may be font related. Your supervisor may have used a font on her macOS system for the comments which is not available in Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: @IconDaemon Ah yes, I think you're right. That seems to be a better interpretation of the question! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth Thanks :) My supervisor said that she used preview for commenting, but I can't open and see them at all.